# problema con pestañas en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en `tkinter` con pestañas las cuales son dos, que son:

- Venta1
- Venta2

Cuando pongo que mis botones salgan en la pestaña venta 1 aparece completamente blanco.

Aquí una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿No sé por qué sale esto? He revisado el código y creo que esta bien. Si alguien sabe como ayudarme, lo agradeceria mucho.

Aquí mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ventana = Tk()

ventana.title("softnum_empleados")

ventana.geometry('900x800')

tad_control=ttk.Notebook(ventana)
tad_control.pack()
tad_control.grid(column=0, row=1)
tad1=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad2=ttk.Frame(tad_control)

tad_control.add(tad1, text="ventas 1")
tad_control.add(tad2, text="ventas 2")

boton1=Button(tad1, text="VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)

boton2=Button(tad1, text="DEVOLUCIONES", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton2.place(x=500, y=400)

        
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: tus botones no aparecen por que a los `Frames` no le estas dando geometría si le pasas estos argumentos a tus frames veras que aparecerán `width=500, height=500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Bienvenido a Stackoverflow!, antes de nada te recomiendo un nombre algo mas legible, aunque he de reconocer que me has sacado una sonrisa xD.

He encontrado el problema al final del código donde asignas cada botón a cada instancia/pestaña, lo que llamas "tad".

Hacer uso de `pack()` para cada botón.

También he refactorizado el código durante el debug a fin de ordenarlo para mi y entender cada linea correctamente agregando comentarios al final, así aclarar el problema.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ventana = Tk() # Crea instancia
ventana.title("softnum_empleados") # Poner titulo en instancia
ventana.geometry('900x800') # Tamanio de la instancia / ventana

tad_control=ttk.Notebook(ventana) # Control de pestanias

tad1=ttk.Frame(tad_control) # Crear pestania y situarla en el control de pestanias
tad_control.add(tad1, text="ventas 1") # Agregar la penstania 1

tad2=ttk.Frame(tad_control)
tad_control.add(tad2, text="ventas 2") # Agregar la penstania 2
tad_control.pack() # Agregar/activar el componente
tad_control.grid(column=0, row=1)

boton1 = Button(tad1, text="VENTAS", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton1.place(x=200, y=400)
boton1.pack() # Agregar/activar el boton
boton2 = Button(tad1, text="DEVOLUCIONES", width=19, height=6, bg="yellow")
boton2.place(x=500, y=400)
boton2.pack() # Agregar/activar el boton

    
ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no es correcto `Concretamente falta hacer uso ttk para crear el botón`, con esta linea que importo `from tkinter import *` ya le permite usar el widget `Button` sin el ttk

Comment: Aunque el código ejecuta igual y funciona perfectamente, queda corregido el detalle. Gracias Salvador

Comment: muchas gracias Sergio :)